# Art Photobook in English

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, terminology

I am looking for books that contains photos of paintings and/or statues, historical buildings. These books are typically used as a sort of art gallery on high-quality paper, but I don't know the specific name in the English language.

Answer (score 9):

In the industry they're called "art books", but everyone actually calls them "coffee-table books".

(Because people leave them on their coffee tables -- the long, low table in front of the couch -- to make guests think they're cultured.)

Comment: Are you slightly biased im saying that? I'm joking, I know that such books are rarely even browsed through after getting them, I have a whole sheld of them and I don't remember when I last opened one...

Comment: @Paola -- maybe I can't prove what the books are really used for but what *other* purpose do they serve?  Have you ever been leaving the office on a blustery day and said to yourself, "I can't wait to get home and curl up with a **huge picture-book about pre-Columbian Venezuelan pottery**?

Comment: To name a few uses: research (writing, design, film making), reference (painting, 3d modelling), inspiration (example art books of a particular artist or style), or general appreciation (astronomer having books of galaxies and stars).

Answer (score 5):

In book publishing, a book of this size is called a [*folio.*](http://www.trussel.com/books/booksize.htm)

> [Books taller than 13 inches are called folios, and are often too big to sit upright, and have to lie on their sides on a top or bottom shelf, or on a table somewhere. These include what are often called "coffee table books"](http://www.babcockbooks.com/bookSize.php)